# Problems with datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I change the borderstyle of one needable row?

```
dgv_All.DataSource = dt2;
```

and after this i want to change borderstyle of row, for example, number 12.

I've tried some variants, but they don't work.

Comment: are you trying to change border style using datasource property?

Comment: no, i'm trying to change border style using datagridview properties

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [DefaultCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the row after you bind the data.

```
dgv_All.Rows[12].DefaultCellStyle
```

Cheers!

Comment: datagridview rows haven't got Style property(

Comment: Yes it has if you are using a GridView. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I just tried this code before posting. So it works, unless you are using a different type of control :)

Comment: I'm using DataGridView, and if i try your code i have error, that DataGridRow hasn't got definiton for "Style"

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you are referring to a Winforms app. I answered thinking that it's a web app. I just updated my answer.

Comment: It's a pleasure. Have fun with your code. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[valid BorderStyle value.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.borderstyle(v=vs.90).aspx)

DataGridView.BorderStyle Property[BorderStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.borderstyle(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
dgv_All.BorderStyle  = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;;
```

for one row

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_All.Rows)
{
    string RowType = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

    if (RowType == "Type A")
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    else if (RowType == "Type B")
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Comment: this one i know, but it will give that borderstyle to all cells, but i need only for one row.